# Where does this grid variable come from?

Tags: java, static-import

I am looking at the [ColumnGridReport example](http://dynamicreports.sourceforge.net/examples/columngridreport.html) for DynamicReports.

I would like to use the classic code syntax instead of the DSL used in the example, meaning creating

```
JasperReportBuilder report = DynamicReports.report();
```

and using `report.addColumn(...)` and so on, but I can't figure out how to do that for the "columnGrid" part:

```
          report
          .columnGrid(   
            grid.verticalColumnGridList(   
                itemColumn,   
                grid.horizontalColumnGridList(quantityColumn,   unitPriceColumn)),   
            grid.verticalColumnGridList(   
                orderDateColumn,   
                grid.horizontalColumnGridList(orderDateFColumn, orderYearColumn),   
                grid.horizontalColumnGridList(orderMonthColumn, orderDayColumn)));
```

There is a variable `grid` ... where is that even initialized?

Basically I would like to do `report.columnGrid(`how to initialize the inside part`)`.

How can I transform this to the classic syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's one static import in the file:

```
import static net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.DynamicReports.*;
```

As you can see in [this Javadoc documentation](http://dynamicreports.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/dynamicreports/report/builder/DynamicReports.html), `grid` is a static field in `DynamicReports`.

Answer (score 0):

You can import "grid" like this

```
import static net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.DynamicReports.grid;
```